# Discord.py New error with on_message_delete(message) after updating Python version

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So, in short, basically half of my code isn't working since updating Python and redirecting a new pip - I read this is common and I'm not sure how to fix it but 1 step at a time. The quick thing I want to fix is this:

```
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if message.author.bot == False:
        if message.channel.id != <censored>:
            em = discord.Embed(title=str(message.author),description="deleted a message.", color=red)
            if len(str(message.content)) < 1000:
                em.add_field(name = str(message.content), value="(message contents)")
            else:
                em.add_field(name = "[content greater than 1000 characters]", value="(message contents)")
            em.add_field(name = str(message.channel), value="(location)")
            events_channel = bot.get_channel(<censored>)
            await events_channel.send(embed=em)
```

Now I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alipe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 373, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alipe\Desktop\Discord Server\Luna.py", line 677, in on_message_delete
    await events_channel.send(embed=em)
  File "C:\Users\alipe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1419, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\alipe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 501, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embeds.0.fields.0.name: This field is required
```

The content isn't over 2000 characters but as you can see, I already have an if/else for that exact situation. Sorry if this is a simple solution, thank you for any help.

Note: I have tried adding `await bot.process_commands(message)` since I have more on_ situations that aren't even running but this made no difference.

Since this is bigger than this, here is an idea of what is and isn't working, vaguely:

**Working:**

- on_ready (a print statement, an activity presence update)
- all existing embeds with role reactions work as desired
- on_invite functions

**Not Working:**

- all commands
- calling any embeds
- any on_message functions

For visibility, all my imports:

```
from discord import Color
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, CheckFailure
import dislash
from dislash import InteractionClient, SelectMenu, SelectOption, ActionRow, Button, ButtonStyle
import os, random, json, time, asyncio, sys, traceback, calendar
```

pip freeze:

```
aiohttp==3.7.4.post0
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==21.4.0
chardet==4.0.0
discord==1.7.3
discord.py @ git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@515d17405a9eda9f457746193b9b8722ab17b2e6
dislash.py==1.4.9
disnake==2.4.0
idna==3.3
multidict==6.0.2
typing_extensions==4.1.1
yarl==1.7.2
```

**update**: uh.. so the commands and such work in DMs to the bot but not in my server...so that's a big chunk of info that should help me figure out what's wrong

Comment: It's possible—but uncommon—for an update of Python itself (within 3, anyway) to break code. An update to a library you're using seems more likely. Do you know what versions you were using previously, and have you tried installing those same versions in your new Python environment? That could at least help you narrow it down. (Of course, it's also possible that the problem is a change in Discord's API, and the timing is a coincidence. Stranger things have happened.) Also, what version of Python were you using prior to 3.10?

Comment: I did (the best I can tell) reinstall every library successfully but I can try rerunning those installations again and separately. I'm learning that pretty much every on_message type event gives me the same error but also every single one of my commands is broken. only on_invitation_create() seems to work...and existing embeds with role reactions, every single thing apart from those doesn't work lol it's bizarre.

Comment: I mean the same version number, not just the same libraries. They may very well have updated since you last modified your environment, and unless you tell it otherwise, pip installs the latest versions available.

Comment: The only library I'm using is dislash and that's fully installed. I'll paste my imports above in the OP

Comment: more helpful would be the output of `pip freeze`

Comment: posted pip freeze

Comment: I added an update at the very bottom, I'm glad I tried this. Now I'm confused why that's a thing but it's a huge step forward

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the update of the python version. `message.content` can be empty (only a file send for example). In a consequence the name of the field is an empty string which is invalid and will raise the described error, because it still will execute the if part of the if else code.

Comment: this same error is happening with on_message_edit and on_message in general..

Comment: yeah but this error traceback doesn't indicate anything else then there is a field with an invalid name. If you have other tracebacks you should share them with us

Comment: Depending on if it's delete or edit, delete being the long version of the error. the on_message_edit error gives me one line: 
In embeds.0.fields.1.value: This field is required -
which is fields.1.value instead of fields.0.value.
as for my on_message(), it doesn't send any error, it just doesn't execute

Comment: but weirdly...these used to work earlier today until I decided to update my python version like I said

Comment: post them above please

Comment: and to what python version did you upgrade?

Comment: I went from 3.7.6 to 3.10.3

Answer (score 1):

The issue with nothing working is an extra requirement needed when I updated to the latest version of discord.py message_intents enabled.